# Basic Android : how to handle isPressed action on a button in Android

Tags: java, android, onclick

I wrote a working code using isEnabled().

```
    if(btn.isEnabled()){    
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    

        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {   
    // say send a udp packet  
        }  
        }  

    );  
    }
```

Now instead of the packet to be sent when the button is clicked, I want to send it when it stays pressed. How do I handle this? 
when i tried isPressed instead of isEnabled, there was a blank screen and the activity was not even displayed...

EDIT : also tried btn.isPressed() - it doesn't work ... the udp packet gets sent immediately after I click on the button... I want it to send ONLY when I am pressing it ...

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to do something when the user clicks the button, AND keeps the finger on it so it? Please clarify.

Comment: the udp packet gets sent immediately after I click on the button... I want it to send ONLY when I am pressing it ... I don't want any action on click ... only when he keeps the finger on it... pl help

Answer (score 1):

your condition is vague. "ONLY when I am pressing it" would mean you'll start sending when the button starts being pressed, which would mean on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. if you want some delay before the action gets executed, create a timer thread that would start when `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is detected, and will execute your action after a few seconds. the timer should also reset when `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is detected, or if the action is already in progress, interrupt the action.

but honestly, you may want to rephrase your condition.

Comment: this does seem like the correct solution to your stated problem... are you sure you're implementing it the way the other example was shown?

Comment: OR, are you looking for OnLongClickListener?

Comment: instead of the timer, I could terminate the UDP connection ... but that seems inefficient ?... I think it's "phrased" perfectly.

Comment: I am using onTouchListener and MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN . Why'd I need OnLongClickListener

Comment: I re-read the question and maybe to clarify- "Is it possible to send packets (think voice) when the button is pressed and then terminate the connection when the button is relesaed?"

Comment: as i mentioned in my answer, "or if the action is already in progress, interrupt the action". also, how would you know it it's not just "clicked" without a timer?

Comment: you can follow this example on how to make a countdown timer http://dewful.com/?p=3

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but worth a try

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(v.isPressed()){
            //do sth.   
            }
            else{
            //do sth. else  
            }

        }
```

Comment: No That didn't work ... Should it be inside the setOnclickListener ?   if(btnTalk.isEnabled()){
   btnTalk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.isPressed()){   ???!

Comment: also tried btn.isPressed() - it doesn't work ... the udp packet gets sent immediately after I click on the button... I want it to send ONLY when I am pressing it ...

Answer (score 0):

Your going to want to use the onTouchListener instead of onClick and stuff. Small change you also want to track when the user lets go.

**EDIT** adding timer stuff

```
Timer timer;
UDP request;
btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
         if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
             //TODO start sending udp in background
             timer = new Timer();
             timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                    request.start();
                }
             },DELAY_MS);

         }
         if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
             //TODO stop sending udp
             timer.cancel()

             if(request.isTransmitting()){ 
                request.stop();
             }
         }
         //needed to get both calls
         return true;
     }
});
```

Comment: using the above just define a timer in action down and cancel it on action up. your also going to want add some form of canceling to the request not just the timer. so your going to want the request and timer as class variables.